# how to show pdf thumbnail on ios if my pdf file is on server

Tags: ios, pdf, thumbnails

I am new to iOS development. In my application I want to display thumbnail of PDF file which is available on the server. Client wants thumbnail first and then the whole page. It will be great if you send me some links with sample.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create the thumbnail on the server, and download it on the iOS app. Then download the pdf in a second stage.

If you need a simple solution to show web images, use EGOImageLoading:
http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html

For displaying the PDF, you can use Apple's QuickLook, or some more sophisticated frameworks (http://pspdfkit.com)

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but for reference purpose, I would like to mention that its much easier to draw the thumbnails at the sync time and before actually loading the view.